# CUDA Access Network Card by GPU via gpudirect or GPDMA

Tags: networking, cuda, gpu

I have an "HP NC365T 4-port Ethernet Server Adapter" which is a PCI Express adapter. I also have a Kepler-class GPU with DMA (Direct Memory Access). 
I would like to be able to directly transfer data from a socket on the adapter to the GPU, i.e. I don’t want the data to be transferred first to the CPU and then from the CPU to the GPU. 
How can this be done? Do I need to use the capabilities of the adapter driver or the driver would not be involved? Ideally I am looking for some sample code to achieve the above.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have access to the driver source code (or a GPUDirect-compliant driver and stack is already available from the network card vendor), it's not possible to achieve this.

If you have access to the driver source code, the starting point would be to begin with the documentation provided [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#abstract).

A full tutorial is outside of the scope of an answer I can provide here.

Comment: i read this page and only say it is possible but not detail ,by unified virtual addressing in maxwell gpus we can access to another pci express devices but in kelper gpus we have p2p access . is it way to show me how can i access NIC data memory or is the general source that can use in cuda?